# Why AsyncTaskLoader is deprecated in Android P?

Tags: android, background, android-loader, asynctaskloader, android-9.0-pie

According to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html), AsyncTaskLoader is deprecated in Android P. 
Can anyone tell me why they are deprecated and what alternative should we used instead?

EDIT - google now recommends using ViewModel instead of Loader that's the reason for their deprecation

Answer (score 5):

> Can anyone tell me why they are deprecated

The framework implementation of `Loader` is deprecated, along with the framework implementation of `Fragment`.

> what alternative should we used instead?

Use [the Support Library edition of `AsyncTaskLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html).

Comment: google now recommends using ViewModel instead of Loader that's the reason for their deprecation.

Comment: @HiteshBisht Where do you see it? I see that it's not deprecated yet: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/loader/content/AsyncTaskLoader .